# symfony: trying to set a field inside executeUpdate()

Tags: forms, symfony1

I have just generated a module and I'm trying to set the value of a
field before saving it this way:

```
  public function executeUpdate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {

    $this->process = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $this->form = $this->configuration->getForm($this->process);

    $this->form['user_process_list'] = array(1,2); //this is my code
```

but I'm getting this error:

> "Cannot update form fields."

So, how can I set it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception with "Cannot update form fields." message is thrown while trying to access form field which doesn't exist.

Anyway, the right place for updating form values is in the form itself. You can update value of any field with [updateXXXColumn()](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/form/sfFormDoctrine.class.php) method (where XXX is a PHP name of the column):

```
public function updateUserProcessListColumn($value)
{
  return array(1, 2);
}
```

Of course the field needs to exist in the form and appropriate column in your model as well.

Comment: Thanks kuba. I have a many-to-many relationship (User-UserGroup-Group). So when I generate the User form class I find a field called "user_group_list" that is is showed in a module based on User model. As you say, I created a function updateUserGroupList(){return array(1,2)} but when I submit the form it doesn't create a UserGroup row... The "user_group_list" has two elements with the values 1 and 2 that i created in the fixtures file. I put inside that function a die("entro") and "entro" is showed. Any idea?